# how to add an object to a set of some generic type in java with iterator?

Tags: java, oop, generics, types, casting

I need to add elements from a `LinkedList` in a class to a `Set`. I tried to code the method; iterate , and then just add `set.add(it.next())` but it did not work because the compiler said that `it.next()` is an `Object`,  while my list contains elements of a generic type `E`, and so should my `Set`. Here is my approach :

```java
Set<E> selectUniques() {
    Set<E> set= new HashSet<>();
            
    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        if (frequency(it.next()) == 1) {
            try {
                E newob=(E) it.next();
                set.add(newob); 
            }
            catch( ClassCastException e) {
                System.out.println("wrong list element type");
            }  
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

I know that since `E extends Object`, performing the cast that I did there is not alright. If there is a better solution even if it's without iterators? Note that I don't have the right to add parameters.

Comment: Why not `Iterator<E> it`? Bear in mind you're calling `next()` twice there btw

Answer (score 3):

`Iterator` is also a generic class, so you can and should use `Iterator<E>` instead of a raw `Iterator`:

```java
Iterator<E> it = list.iterator();
```

With that, `next()` will return an `E` instead of a plain old `Object`, and your compilation issue should be solved.

**EDIT:**
As Bohemian pointed out in the comments - make sure your `list` is a `List<E>` and not a raw `List` too.

Comment: The list itself may need typing too. Perhaps OP's IDE created a raw Iterator because the list is raw.

Comment: @Bohemian fair point, edited this in to my answer.